# Can I push user input from a program

Tags: c

Sorry, title might not make much sense, wasn't sure what to name it.

```
//history of the 10 previous commands
char *history[10][140];

while (1) {
    printf("Enter command:");
    fgets(input, MAX, stdin);

    //Handle other commands

    //true if user entered command to call previous command
    if(thisIsTrue){
        //strToInt gets number from the user input
        int histNum = strToInt(input);
        char *nextinput = history[histNum];

        //Not sure what to do here

    }
}
```

So, I am able to get the nextinput that is needed, however I am not sure how to pass this into the next loop because most commands are taken from the user entering a command, for this if statement(if the user entered a particular command) an old command needs to be executed.  I store old commands in history and able to get the next input that is needed, I am just not sure how to pass it through the next loop.  Is there a way to simulate user input so fgets will pickup nextinput or how else will i do this? (Would prefer to not copypaste all of (//handle other commands) in the if statement.

```
Example of program running:
Enter command:command1
Enter command:command2
Enter command:command3
Enter command:command4
Enter command:command5
Enter command:command6
Enter command:command7
Enter command:command8
Enter command:command9
Enter command:command10
Enter command:command11
Enter command:command1
Enter command:hlist
    4 command4
    5 command5
    6 command6
    7 command7
    8 command8
    9 command9
    10 command10
    11 command11
    12 command1
    13 hlist
Enter command:!11
command11  //this is the value of new_input
```

I just don't know how to push command11 into the while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood what you are asking, it must look something like this:

```
char *history[rows][columns];
int user_has_requested_previous_command_flag = 0;

while(1)
{
    switch(user_has_requested_previous_command_flag)
    {
        case 0:
            printf("Enter command:");
            fgets(input, MAX, stdin);
            //Handle other commands
            if(thisIsTrue)
            {
                //strToInt gets number from the user input
                int histNum = strToInt(input);
                input = history[histNum];
                user_has_requested_previous_command_flag = 1; // !!!!!!!!!
            }
            break;

        case 1:
            // Do whatever you need to do here with the previous input from the history
            user_has_requested_previous_command_flag = 0;
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char *history[10][140];
```

means that you have a two dimensional array 10*140, each element of that array is not a character but a string (`char*`). Hardly that what you wanted.

```
chr *nextinput = history[histNum];
```

Are you sure it is `chr` and not `char` ?

Further, if it is really `char *nextinput = history[histNum];` , then it is wrong, since history is a 2d array.

Comment: Sorry, yes char not chr,  however  char *nextinput = history[histNum]; works completely fine, I just don't know how to push it into fgets (if its even possible) or how else to I would push the next command through that program.

Comment: You can't push it into `fgets()`. You need to implement logic that gets the value from the history array instead of calling `fgets()`.